# Proof that a given set is a field

Tags: field-theory

**I am solving the following exercise (linear algebra):**

*show that: $\ \mathbb{Q}\lbrack\sqrt{2}\rbrack = \{ a + b\cdot\sqrt{2} \ \vert \ a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subset \mathbb{R} \ $ is a field, with the addition and multiplication of the real numbers.*

**Background**: First of all, i am a first semester mathematics student and we had not covered a lot so far. In our lectures we had  the definition of a group, abelian group and of a field so far.

**Problem:** The sentence *"with addition and multiplication of reall numbers"* confuse me because I dont understand if i have to apply the field axioms to an element of the set $\mathbb{Q}\lbrack\sqrt{2}\rbrack$ and one of $\mathbb{R}$ or just to element of the set. Further I have no clue how to start that proof. If anyone could give me some helpfull piece of advice i would be very happy about.

Comment: The phrasing simply means that you add and multiply numbers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ just like you add and multiply any real numbers. So $(a+b\sqrt{2})+(c+d(\sqrt{2})=(a+b)+(c+d)\sqrt{2}$, and so forth. (PS: Don't use $*$ for multiplication outside of programming. In mathematics, it has other uses. Write `\cdot` to get $\cdot$.)

Comment: Uh, bad typo in my previous comment: Should be $(a+b\sqrt{2})+(c+d(\sqrt{2})=(a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I thought about that meaning aswell, but i was not sure. It makes only sense in that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The proof in some steps:

- The set $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ isn't empty
- if $u=a+b\sqrt2$ and $u'=a'+b'\sqrt2$ are in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ then $u-u'\in \Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$
- if $u=a+b\sqrt2$ and $u'=a'+b'\sqrt2$ are in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ , $u'\ne0$ then $u(u')^{-1}\in \Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$

so if you prove these points then you proved that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$  is a sub-field of $(\Bbb R ,+,\times)$.

Comment: These are quite minimalistic requirements. For a beginner, it makes more sense to show that $0$ and $1$ belong, and the purported field is closed under addition, negation, multiplication, and inverses. Here, inverses is the trickiest part.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to proof that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is an abelian group in terms of $ \cdot$ and $+$. I am struggling with an idea to proof that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is not empty. I was thinking about the idea to show that the union of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and $ \emptyset $ is not empty.